# Access XCOM values outside operator

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, astronomer

I need to access XCOM values outside the operator, it can be done using variables, but i want to avoid it.

I am pushing the xcom values from one operator and then a funcction to fetch xcom values using getone/getmany function, but it is returning null/none.

even chatgpt is not providing correct result.

please have look at the below code and help fix it?

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.models.xcom import XCom
from airflow.utils.session import provide_session

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'provide_context': True
}


from airflow.models import DagRun, Variable
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


def last_task_func(**kwargs):
    value1 = kwargs["value1"]
    value2 = kwargs["value2"]
    value3 = kwargs["value3"]
    value4 = kwargs["value4"]
    value5 = kwargs["value5"]
    final_value=f"{value1}-{value2}-{value3}-{value4}-{value5}"
    print(f"value -- {final_value}")
    return final_value


def my_previous_task_func(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs["ti"]
    ti.xcom_push(key="key1", value='xcom_value 1')
    ti.xcom_push(key="key2", value='xcom_value 2')
    ti.xcom_push(key="key3", value='xcom_value 1')


dag_id = "test_xcom_dag"


@provide_session
def get_xcom_value(session):
    # Get the current DAG run ID from the Variable store
    current_dag_run_id = "{{run_id}}"
    # Variable.get("dag_run").get(dag_id)

    # Get the current DAG run object
    # current_dag_run = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id, run_id=current_dag_run_id)

    # Get the XCom values for the current DAG run
    # xcom_keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
    xcom_keys = 'key1'
    t_id='my_previous_task'
    # xcom_values = XCom.get_many(run_id= current_dag_run_id, key=None, task_ids=None, dag_ids=dag_id,session=session)
    
    xcom_values = XCom.get_one(key=xcom_keys, task_id=t_id, dag_id=dag_id, run_id= current_dag_run_id,session=session)
    # Use the XCom values
    value1 = xcom_values
    # value2 = xcom_values['key2']
    # value3 = xcom_values['key3']
    value2 = 'val 2'
    value3 = 'val 3'
    print(value1, value2, value3)
    # xcom = value1.with_entities(XCom.value).first()
    return xcom_values
    # if xcom:
    #    return XCom.deserialize_value(xcom)


with DAG(
    dag_id,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 16),
    schedule_interval=None,
    max_active_runs=1,
    description='description',
    catchup=False,
    default_args=args,
    ) as dag:

    my_previous_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='my_previous_task',
        python_callable=my_previous_task_func,
        provide_context=True,
        do_xcom_push=True
    )

    current_dag_run_id = "{{run_id}}"
    xcom_keys = 'key1'
    t_id='my_previous_task'
    
    value1=get_xcom_value()

    last_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='last_task',
        python_callable=last_task_func,
        op_kwargs={"value1": value1,"value2":current_dag_run_id, "value3":dag_id, "value4":xcom_keys, "value5":t_id},
        provide_context=True,
        do_xcom_push=True
    )

    my_previous_task >> last_task
```

Comment: Do not try to access Xcoms outside of operator scope. Yes you can find a way to work around by directly querying the DB but this is might/will overwhelm the DB with queries as DAGs are parsed every 30 seconds. Don't go there.

Comment: Thanks @EladKalif, for the response, but i have the requirement to use the XCOM outside scope to generate dynamic tasks in a task group with help of the XCOM value from one task.

Comment: This is not how it should be done. Check dynamic task mapping feature. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html

Comment: are you trying to get xcom value within `last_task_func`?  The code looks like you are getting xcom value and passing to `last_task_func` but the `last_task_func` already have access to xcom natively within the function.  `kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='my_previous_task', key='key1')`